# adding items to list string but getting null reference exception

Tags: c#, winforms

I am adding items to string list and i know there is data that exists to insert but i keep getting the null reference error message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
    public class ExcelRow
        {
            public List<String> lstCells;
            public byte[] rowHash;
            ......
        }
    public class ExcelInfo
        {
            public List<ExcelRow> excelRows;
        }

    public ExcelInfo ReadExcel(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog)
        {
            var _excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(openFileDialog.FileName);
            var _info = from c in _excelFile.WorksheetNoHeader() select c;

            ExcelRow excelRow;
            ExcelInfo resp;

            resp = new ExcelInfo();

            foreach (var item in _info)
            {
                excelRow = new ExcelRow();
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(0));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(1));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(2));
                excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(3));
                .....
                excelRow.CalculateHash();
                resp.excelRows.Add(excelRow);
             }
            return resp;
       }
```

This is where i am getting the error: `excelRow.lstCells.Add(item.ElementAt(0));`

Comment: you never instantiate the `List<ExcelRow>`

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your `lstCells` in your `ExcelRow` constructor:

```
public class ExcelRow {
  public List<String> lstCells;
  public byte[] rowHash;
  public ExcelRow(){
     lstCells = new List<string>();
  }
  //....
}

public class ExcelInfo {
  public List<ExcelRow> excelRows = new List<ExcelRow>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for adding all my items but now i am getting the same thing when i hit `resp.excelRows.Add(excelRow);` and i could see that excelRow does contain items

Comment: While at it, `ExcelInfo.excelRows` is never initialized either from the code shown.

Comment: @Masriyah yes, you have also to initialize the `excelRows`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing your `ExcelRow` constructor, but from the error, I am guessing you never instantiate `lstCells` and it remains null.

You could find this out by debugging your program and mousing over each item in the line or methodically removing one item at a time from the line until it starts working again. and deducing the problem.